# Removing objects created by another class in Lua / Corona SDK and storyboard

Tags: oop, memory-leaks, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to figure out the best way to fix a memory leak in my app and use external classes.  I am coding in Corona SDK and using Storyboard.    I don't think I am removing objects properly when I create them through classes.  Can you take a look and help with the following

1) At the bottom of the code, I show how I remove the keyboard.  Is that sufficient or do I need to do more since the keyboard was created through another file?

2) in keyboard.lua , I need to create the objects in a way that thekeyboard.lua file can manipulate them with functions later.   I did this by declaring theKeyboard, theCursor, theBackground.

Is there any reason to do that vs calling them M.theKeyboard, M.theCursor, M.theBackground and not declaring them in advance since M is local?

3) Would you implement this keyboard class differently?  If so, can you give me pointers?

Here is example code.  I want to reuse this keyboard code across my app.  There should only be one keyboard at anytime.   I want to remove the keyboard completely when the user exits the scene because many screens do not require the keyboard.

```
-- keyboard.lua
local M = {}
local theKeyboard, theCursor, theBackground

function M.newBackground()
    if theBackground then 
       theBackground = nil
    end
    local newBackground = display.newRect(0,0,0,0)
    -- set position, size, color, etc
    theBackground = newBackground
    return newBackground
end

... many other functions to create cursor, textlabels, etc

function M.newKeyboard()
    if theKeyboard then 
       theKeyboard = nil
    end
    theKeyboard = display.newGroup()
    theCursor = M.newCursor()
    theBackground = M.newBackground()

    --  lots more stuff... like I create buttons for each key on the keyboard

    theKeyboard:insert(theCursor)
    theKeyboard:insert(theBackground)
    return theKeyboard
end

function M.removeKeyboard()
   display.remove(theCursor)
   display.remove(theBackground)
   display.remove(theKeyboard)
   theCursor = nil
   theBackground = nil
   theKeyboard = nil
end

return M
```

and then my app uses storyboard so here's an example of how I integrate the keyboard into a scene.

```
local keyboard = require ( "keyboard" )
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

local keyboardGroup, otherobjects 

function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    keyboardGroup = keyboard.newKeyboard
    group:insert( keyboardGroup )
    end
end

-- other code


-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)
function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    --  Is this sufficient for removing the keyboard completely?
        keyboard.removeKeyboard()
        keyboardGroup = nil
    end
end


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- additional code that comes with storyboard

return scene
```

Comment: I didn't check the code but before starting, may I ask you that did you use garbage collector in an enterframe function? Because without that you may have some memory problems

Comment: I didn't use a garbage collector.  I didn't know there was one.  But even still, I'd like to fix all memory leaks first and then use a garbage collector as a last resort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try -

```
if theKeyboard then 
   theKeyboard:removeSelf()
   theKeyboard = nil
end
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I had this before .. or I was doing display.remove(theKeyboard) but I had problems where there were times when the Keyboard existed but was already removed from display and this caused crashes.  I will investigate that.

Comment: In this case, you have to use local "theKeyboard" for each & every method instead of a global "theKeyboard".You can also store "theKeyboard" value in a variable and paas it to when its value required.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback.  Nobody answered the question but you did provide some information to help me investigate more

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @Varsha say, you should have this code block. In corona its not enough to just remove objects. collectgarbage() function do the main work. Whenever you type object = nil afterwards it will be deleted by garbage collector.

```
local monitorMem = function() -- Garbage collector

    collectgarbage()
    --print( "MemUsage: " .. collectgarbage("count") )

    local textMem = system.getInfo( "textureMemoryUsed" ) / 1000000
    --print( "TexMem:   " .. textMem )
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", monitorMem )
```

Comment: Ya.. I use this in my development environment when I want to check for memory leaks.  I didn't know whether I should be using it in production. I was told you should not use it in production and that lua does garbage collection automatically when needed.